Is there a way to disable the workshop widgets?
I am trying to disable string selector or filter list widget as per user switching tabs. I am not able to see any option to do that in workshop. Is there a way to disable widgets in workshop?

Yes, you can!
You have put the feature "String Selector" in any of the section that contains the CONDITIONAL VISIBILITY feature which uses a Boolean variable whether you want to show the section or not.
on TAB switching you can add the event which is a set variable value, over there you can dynamically change the Boolean variable value, and according to that, your "String Selector" section gets hidden.

You can also find the Disable button there.

Yeah, I want to disable the widget instead of hide it. Looking a way to do it in workshop.

you can check the updated answer, do let me know if you want a detailed overview
